# AS3 FLVPlayback with progressive .mp4

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, progressive-download

So I have a dynamically created FLVPlayback object and for the most part everything is working just peachy.

However, when I load an MP4 file (via HTTP) with it, it will not play until the entire file is downloaded.

After doing some research, I used QTIndexSwapper2 to put the 'moov' atom at the beginning of the file, but it did not help.

Any ideas or suggestions? Using an RTMP server is not an option right now.

Many thanks.

**EDIT** 
The video starts playing when the buffering bar reaches about 80%. I don't know if this is just an inaccuracy in the buffering bar or if it's actually playing the video before it's fully downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Here some possible solutions:

1. Try to rename the file to `*.f4v`
2. Check what content type your server is sending (should be i.e. video/mp4)
3. If using IIS have a look at [Pseudostreaming extension](http://h264.code-shop.com/trac/wiki/Mod-H264-Streaming-Internet-Information-Services-IIS-Version2)

Comment: Thanks for the response. The server I was testing it with is using Apache... in the end product however, the client will be hosting the videos on a server of their choosing so I will not have any control over extensions etc. Renaming to '.f4v' had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I re-encoded the videos as F4V files using Adobe Media Encoder. They seem to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and rendering with F4V(after effects) solved this issue.